# Table column width and horizontal alignment

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I searched all over the internet and cannot find a simple solution to stretch table columns to the content width, and how to centralize table in the middle of the screen. It is always aligned to the left. I tried `<TableColumn width="Auto">`. It did not do a trick. The only thing worked was `<TableColumn width="200">`. How can I cause columns to stretch to the content width, and how can I put table in middle of the screen? Or, should I just resort to the Grid option?

Here is my XAML:

```
<src:BaseSurveyElement x:Class="Question14"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:src="clr-namespace:DAQExperiment"
Title="Question14" FontStyle="Normal" FontSize="20" WindowState="Maximized" >

<Grid Height="600" Width="1100">


    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- <FlowDocumentReader Grid.Row="0" Name="FlowDocReader" Margin="2 2 2 2" ViewingMode="Scroll"/> -->
    <TextBlock Name="txtBlock" Grid.Row="0" Margin="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    <!--<ScrollViewer Height="500" Width="1100"  Grid.Row="1"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" CanContentScroll="True">-->

        <FlowDocumentReader Grid.Row="1" UseLayoutRounding="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="1200">
            <FlowDocumentReader.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TableCell">
                    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>
            </FlowDocumentReader.Resources>
            <FlowDocument  >

                <Table CellSpacing="0" TextAlignment="Justify"  >
                    <Table.Columns >
                        <TableColumn />
                        <TableColumn />
                        <TableColumn />
                        <TableColumn />
                        <TableColumn />
                        <TableColumn />
                        </Table.Columns>
                <TableRowGroup Paragraph.TextAlignment="Center" >
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                                <Paragraph FontWeight="Bold"></Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell BorderBrush="Black" ColumnSpan="2" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1">
                                <Paragraph FontWeight="Bold">Option A</Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell BorderBrush="Black" ColumnSpan="2" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1">
                                <Paragraph FontWeight="Bold">Option B</Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1">

                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1">
                                <Paragraph FontWeight="Bold">Subscription</Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                                <Paragraph>Monthly</Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                                <Paragraph>Yearly</Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                                <Paragraph>Monthly</Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                            <Paragraph>Monthly</Paragraph>
                         </TableCell>
                         <TableCell BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                            <Paragraph>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  Margin="10,5,10,10" Name="spl1RdBtn">
                                    <RadioButton  GroupName="rbtngrp1" Content="Choice A" Margin="0,0,20,0" Name="rbtn1A" />
                                    <RadioButton GroupName="rbtngrp1" Content="Choice B" Margin="0,0,20,0" Name="rbtn1B" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Paragraph>
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" TextAlignment="Center">
                                <Paragraph FontWeight="Bold">Price</Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                                <Paragraph>$120.00</Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                                <Paragraph>$1000.00</Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                                <Paragraph>$130.00</Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableRowGroup>
                </Table>
            </FlowDocument>
        </FlowDocumentReader>
    <!--</ScrollViewer>-->

</Grid>

<Window.Background>
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,0" StartPoint="0.5,1">
        <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="0" />
        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</Window.Background>
```

And here is what I get as a result:
[image]

Answer (score -2):

To make table center aligned

```
<Table HorizontalAlignment="Centre" VerticalAlignment="Center">
```

& to make column width try using * instead of Auto or put some number and then * like "2*"

Comment: Cannot set unknown member 'System.Windows.Documents.table.VerticalAlignment'.